# Тире по месту «а именно»

Tags: пунктуация, тире

*Однако, в небольшой бывшей советской республике — в Молдавии, многим знаком этот тезис*.

Нужен ли повторяющийся предлог? Смысл тире и запятой в обособлении названия?

Comment: Цитата пошире: «Именно коллективный Запад может инициировать переговоры о ее разделе!
Для отдельных читателей эта мысль может показаться далекой от реальности. Однако, в небольшой бывшей советской республике – в Молдавии, многим знаком этот тезис».

Answer (score 2):

Я предпочла бы такой вариант оформления:

***Однако в бывшей небольшой советской республике Молдавии*** // ***многим знаком этот тезис.***

(Интонация простого предложения, графически обозначена произносительная пауза.)

Союз ОДНАКО не обособляется: в начале предложения, между однородными членами предложения, между частями сложносочиненного предложения. То же, что «но». http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_504

ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ

Возможен и такой вариант: ***Однако в небольшой бывшей советской респУблике — МолдАвии*** // ***многим знаком этот тезис.***

Здесь второе тире опускается согласно правилу Розенталя  (пункт 10, примечание 2: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111

Произношение в этом случае **без паузы**, но при сохранении **двух ударений**. Второй вариант отличается от первого тем, что в нем подчеркивается **значимость определения**. Учитывая приведенный **контекст**, такая графика действительно кажется **уместной**, хотя на произношении она значительно не сказывается.

Comment: Какие-то ляпы местами... Sharon, исправьте собственной рукой, пожалуйста!

Comment: Ляпы убрала, добавила новый текст и проголосовала за ваш вопрос (тема оказалась интересной).

Comment: Спасибо за ваше время.